# PuTTy Windows SSH doesn't accept UTF-8 password

Tags: windows, ssh, putty

I'm unable to login through ssh using PuTTy on windows. Everything works fine on linux and mac. Any idea or good alternative? I tried changing the character encoding to UTF-8 but no luck there.

**Edit:** Here's all information I have on my setup:

the "error message" from the putty terminal:

```
login as: root
root@server.my.domain.tld's password:
Access denied
```

and the putty settings:

[image: putty settings, main session tab]

[image: putty settings, terminal tab]

[image: putty settings, terminal keyboard tab]

and the linux/mac cli command that works perfectly: 
`ssh root@server.my.domain.tld`

And yes, I'm typing it correctly. I've tried way over 10 times now.

Comment: What error are you getting?  What exactly have you tried? How are you trying to connect?  What works on your Mac/Linux machines?

Comment: well, the error is simply "incorrect password", but it works on non-windows

Comment: As an alternative I'd suggest using SSH key exchange - once set up, provided you keep the keys safe, its very efficient and convenient - and it wont care what encoding your passwords are :)

Comment: I really don't think this is an encoding issue. What command do you use on Mac/Linux?  What fields are you filling into PuTTY and what values are you using?

Comment: I can login to other users, using non-utf8 passwords. Everything works fine then. I'm just using the standard ssh from command line on mac/linux.

Comment: @heavyd do you really need the full bash command and putty settings?

Comment: Just trying to diagnose the problem.  Like I said, I doubt the real issue is encoding, but I can only work with the information you provide.  Your original question provides very little to work with.

Comment: There you go. Everything I think might be related should be in the question now. If you miss anything, tell me. Basically everything is default.